# C - Passing array between functions not giving expected results

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I'm looking to try and pass a char array from one function to another. The array seems to pass into the second function, but the contents of the array seem to be lost, apart from the first element? To get round this I tried duplicating the content of the passed array into a new local array in the called function, but this then opened up the issue of passing the new array back to the original calling function and assigning it's value back to the originally passed in array.

It's likely my pointers could be completely wrong, I'm still getting to grips with pointers in C so have been following tips from the IDE until it stops throwing errors.

Here is how I'm calling the function:

`wordCheck(charIn, randWord, currentWordStatus);`

The array to be updated/modified is the `currrentWordStatus` array.

This is the content of the array when it is passed into the function:

[image]

And here is how it actually ends up in the function:

[image]

Here is the code of my called function:

```
void wordCheck(char guess, char *wordToGuess, char *currentWordStatus) {

    int wordLen = strlen(wordToGuess);
    char wordArr[wordLen];
    strcpy(&wordArr[0], wordToGuess);
    bool found = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < wordLen; i ++) {
        printf("%c \n", (char)wordArr[i]);
        if ((char) wordArr[i] == guess) {
            found = true;
            currentWordStatus[i] = guess;
        }
    }
}
```

I was wondering what I'm doing wrong, I'm hoping to modify the function directly as it is passed 'By Reference' (I'm aware it's a pointer to the start of the array), instead of having to remake the array inside of the function and passing it back.

Hopefully that makes some sort of sense?

Many Thanks

Comment: `char wordArr[wordLen];` should be `char wordArr[wordLen + 1];` because you also need room for the null terminator character at the end of the copied string.

Comment: Note that `&wordArr[0]` is *exactly* equal to `wordArr`. Using the array name when a pointer is expected will *decay* the array to a pointer to its first element.

Comment: All seems to be working now, thank you gents. Very much appreciated!

Comment: You shouldn't actually need to copy the `wordToGuess` string to `wordArr[]` at all. Just use `wordToGuess` directly.

Comment: @IanAbbott I wasn't aware you could index them directly, without copying them into an array. I'm still getting used to how strings are treated in C, coming from languages like Java. Have just tried, works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @JackPollock Yes, array indexing (or rather, "array subscripting" as it is officially known) works on pointers just fine. The C standard calls it "array subscripting", but it should really be called "pointer subscripting", because an expression with array type is converted to an expression of pointer type before the indexing operator (and most other operators) are applied.

Comment: You also don't need the `(char)` cast operator in `(char)wordArr[i]`. It's already a `char`, so the cast is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function all you really have is a pointer to the first element of the array. The program (or the compiler, and as you noticed not even the debugger) doesn't really know what a pointer is really pointing to inside a function.

There's nothing wrong, it's just how C and arrays and pointers in C works.

Comment: Right okay, I see. Does this mean it isn't really possible to pass an array into the function and modify it as I'm planning to? If not, how would you suggest I go about it?

Comment: @JackPollock The code is perfectly valid, as long as you don't go out of bounds of any arrays. You can still use the pointer as an array, and `currentWordStatus[i]` is fine and will work.